# question tuples in regex -regular expressions

Tags: python-3.x

So I have some code on which I will use an regex on.

Specifically, I need to use re.findall() and a single regular expression to extract the three names and email addresses from the 'string'. To create list of 3 tuples like so: [('Mary Boe', 'md90@uw.com'), ('Cheri Moe Drake', 'cmd39@gmail.gbl'), ('R.L. Fitzgeri', 'fit.rl@hotmail.ing')]

here is the string....

```
string = """Name: Mary Boe, Email: md90@uw.com\n
Name: Cheri Moe Drake, Email: cmd39@gmail.gbl\n
Name: R.L. Fitzgeri, Email: fit.rl@hotmail.ing"""
```

So far I have used the following to get ['R.L. Fitzgeri']
with

```
re.findall('\S\S\w\S\s\w\S\w\w\w\w\S\w',string)
```

And I have been able to get fit.rl@hotmail.ing
with

```
re.findall('\w\\w\\w\\S\w\w\S\w\w\w\w\S\w\w\S\w\w\w',string)
```

I have been able to get Cheri Moe Drake with

```
re.findall('\w\w\w\w\w\s\w\w\w\s\w\w\w\w\w',string)
```

But I have struggled condensing this, and secondly, struggled to get it so that it all comes out, as I said, like:

```
[('Mary Boe', 'md90@uw.com'), ('Cheri Moe Drake', 'cmd39@gmail.gbl'), ('R.L. Fitzgeri', 'fit.rl@hotmail.ing')]
```

Comment: Is using regular expression a constraint? There are more efficient ways to approach this.

Comment: Yes blackpearl, it is constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
import re
string =  """Name: Jane Doe, Email: jd12@uw.com\n
Name: Sally Sue Draper, Email: ssd59@gmail.edu\n
Name: J.D. Salinger, Email: sal.jd@hotmail.org"""

pattern = r'Name: (.+?), Email: (.+)'
result = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('Jane Doe', 'jd12@uw.com'), ('Sally Sue Draper', 'ssd59@gmail.edu'), ('J.D. Salinger', 'sal.jd@hotmail.org')]
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
Name:           # literally
(.+?)           # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
, Email:        # literally
(.+)            # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the same format, it may make more sense to avoid regular expressions in this scenario and approach the problem alternatively:

```
string = """Name: Jane Doe, Email: jd12@uw.com\n
Name: Sally Sue Draper, Email: ssd59@gmail.edu\n
Name: J.D. Salinger, Email: sal.jd@hotmail.org"""

people = [person for person in string.split('\n') if person]

people_list = []
for person in people:
    name = ''
    for char in person[6:]:
        if char == ',':
            break
        else:
            name += char

    email = ''
    for char in person[::-1]:
        if char == ' ':
            break
        else:
            email += char
    email = email[::-1]

    person_tuple = (name, email)
    people_list.append(person_tuple)
```

This will give you a list of tuples if you print `people_list`:

```
[('Jane Doe', 'jd12@uw.com'), ('Sally Sue Draper', 'ssd59@gmail.edu'), ('J.D. Salinger', 'sal.jd@hotmail.org')]
```

This assumes that all your lines start with `Name:`, which is why the loop builds a name by concatenating all characters after that up to the first comma it finds.

For the email, it does the same thing in reverse: it takes all characters starting from the end of the string until it finds a space, where the email is effectively ending. It then puts it back in order to get the correct email.

To build the list of contacts, the loop will format `name` and `email` into a tuple that will be appended to `people_list` until there are no more contacts to add.

If you insist on using regular expressions, then a good use for those could be if you want to validate email addresses and not add a contact to your list if the email does not correspond to the format of your choosing (or leave it blank instead). The regex pattern could look like this:

```
email = 'example@email.com'
pattern = r'[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*[\w._-]*@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{1,3}$'
if re.match(pattern, email):
    # do something with email here
```

Note that in this case, the regex uses symbols like `+` and `*` to avoid repetition, which is one of the keys in building a more robust regex.